# How to resubscribe after stopping subscribe in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

After reading the docs about publishing REST resources and stopping subscribe, I was able to code something like this:

(Using Angular-Meteor)

Publish:

```
Meteor.publish('numbers', function(token){

   const res = HTTP.get(API, { headers: {'token-header': token }});

   _.forEach(res.data, (value, key) => {
      this.added('numbers', key, { name: value });
   });

   this.ready();
});
```

Subscribe:

```
class Ctrl{
   constructor($scope, $reactive, $localStorage){
      'ngInject';
      $reactive(this).attach($scope);

      this.subscriber = this.subscribe('numbers', () => {
         return [$localStorage.token];
      });

      this.helpers(){ numbers(){ return Numbers.find(); }}
   }

   refresh(){
      this.subscriber = this.subscribe('numbers', () => {
         return [$localStorage.token];
      }, {
         onReady: () => { console.log('stopping refresh animation'); }
      });
   }
}

//more Angular code...
```

Let's assume that these are the values that the API returns:

```
[ 'Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Foxtrot' ]
```

It all works well on first page load. However, I noticed that when I asked only **Alpha**, **Bravo**, and **Charlie** on refresh, **Delta**, **Echo** and **Foxtrot** still remains in the Minimongo cache.

I tried adding `subscriber.stop()` in the refresh function to remove the data from the cache but I couldn't get `this.subscribe()` to work again.

So I have two questions:

1. How do I subscribe again after stopping subscription?
2. Is there any other way than to subscribe again?

On the other hand, I'm looking at **Apollo** as an alternative. I haven't actually tried it out yet but would you guys recommend it for production assuming that I know what I'm doing with it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel stupid. I was overthinking the problem. Using `Meteor.apply()` would have sufficed with my case.

Here's the code:

Server

```
Meteor.methods({
   'retrieveNumbers' (token){
      const res = HTTP.get(API, { headers: {'token-header': token }});
      return res.data;
   }
});
```

Client

```
class Ctrl{
   constructor($scope, $reactive, $localStorage){
      'ngInject';
      $reactive(this).attach($scope);
      this.$localStorage = $localStorage;

      this.retrieveNumbers();
   }

   retrieveNumbers(){
      this.apply('retrieveNumbers', [this.$localStorage.token], (err, res) => {
         this.numbers= res;
      });
   }
}

//more Angular code...
```

Though I'm still interested if I could turn off subscribe then turn it on back again.

Comment: I believe that you should have cleaned up after your publication on unsubscribe (using a callback). Just as you have called `this.added` when you created the subscription, you should have done `this.removed` when it is stopped (on the server). This is the cost of doing it manually.